# Can a software turn the data to the sound and, Can a microphone listen that sound turn it to the same data

Tags: java, android, audio, microphone

Can a software turn the data to the sound and, Can a microphone listen that sound turn it to the same data?

Actually. I have some data... Can a software encode it in sound like: bass sounds are 1 and tiss sounds are 0... I want to play it on a speaker. And across the room I will have a microphone and it will record that sound. That it will encode it to the same data again. Is this really possible? And what kind of software can do that?

Comment: You seem to be describing a `modem`, with the modulation and demodulation done in software, suggesting that this would be a `software modem`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, morse code is a historical example. There might be ready-made encoders and decoders out there.

When it comes to converting to actual sound and using a microphone, there will always be some loss in fidelity. So your trade-off will be between high data rate and high data fidelity.

For requirements where small transmissions have to be made, this should be completely feasible.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. That's how a modem works - and in some places (old British telephony), they had to use the exact hardware of the phone company, so the modem really would emit noises into the mouthpiece and listen to the earpiece. It sounds like you want something with a lot more tolerance than a classic modem, though; how much data do you need to transmit? Consider the DTMF protocol - that's how touch-tone phones send messages to IVR systems. You could send any of sixteen data values (0-9, *, #, A-D; not many keypads have A-D, but they're part of the spec), and you could adjust your button-press time according to need. You could press each button for half a second, allowing one byte per second of arbitrary data - and a human could listen in on that, which would be a lot of fun :)